# Limit of functions of the form $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x\sin(nx)}{1-\frac{\sin x}{x}}$

Tags: limits

I know how to solve it with the Taylor series. I was wondering if there was a more general explanation without series solution as the limit hovers around 1 as n changes.
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x\sin(nx)}{1-\frac{\sin x}{x}}$$

Comment: You asked without series I did without series way

Comment: Yes you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewrite it as 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2\sin(nx)}{x-\sin x}$$ which is of the form $\frac00$, so we can apply L-Hospital's rule. This is followed by:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x\sin(nx)+x^2 n\cos (nx)}{1-\cos x}$$ which is again of the form $\frac00$, so we can apply L-Hospital's rule again. This is followed by:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin(nx)+2xn\cos nx + n(2x \cos (nx)-nx^2\sin nx)}{\sin x}$$
Divide by $x$ both N&D to get
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}+2n\cos nx + n(2 \cos (nx)-nx\sin nx)}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$$
$$=\frac{2n+2n + n(2-0)}{1}$$
$$=6n$$

Comment: To make the differentiation simpler, you can decompose $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2\sin(nx)}{x-\sin x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x} \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3}{x-\sin x}  $$ before applying the L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x\sin(nx)}{1-\frac{\sin x}{x}}&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2\sin(nx)}{x-\sin x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x\sin(nx)+nx^2\cos (nx)}{1-\cos x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x\sin(nx)+nx^2\cos (nx)}{2\sin^2\frac x2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{8n\sin(nx)}{nx}+4n\cos (nx)}{\frac{2\sin^2\frac x2}{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}}\\
&=\frac{8n+4n}{2}\\
&=6n
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The denominator is asymptotic to $x^2/6$ while the numerator is asymptotic to $nx^2$, so the limit is simply $6n$.

---

Explanations:

$$\sin x= x-x^3/6 + O(x^5)$$

Thus, $$1-\frac{\sin x}x=x^2/6+O(x^4)$$

Similarly, $$\sin nx=nx+O(x^3)$$

Therefore, $$x\sin nx= nx^2 +O(x^4)$$

Comment: Beautiful, thank you